# How to query to get totals for last seven days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I want to write a query that gives me total activity for a number of given days.  Specifically, I want to count total votes per day for the last seven days.

My table looks like this:

```
 VoteID --- VoteDate --------------  Vote --- BikeID

 1          2012-01-01 08:24:25      1        1234 
 2          2012-01-01 08:24:25      0        5678
 3          2012-01-02 08:24:25      1        1289
 4          2012-01-03 08:24:25      0        1234
 5          2012-01-04 08:24:25      1        5645
 6          2012-01-05 08:24:25      0        1213
 7          2012-01-06 08:24:25      1        1234
 8          2012-01-07 08:24:25      0        1125
```

I need my results to look like this

```
VoteDate ---- Total
2012-01-01    5
2012-01-02    6
2012-01-03    7
2012-01-04    1
2012-01-05    3
```

My thought is that I have to do something like this:

```
SELECT    SUM(CASE WHEN Vote = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total
FROM      Votes
GROUP BY  VoteDate
```

This query doesn't work because it counts only votes that occurred (almost exactly) at the same time. Of course, I want to look only at a specific day.  How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cast it as a `date`:

```
SELECT    
     cast(VoteDate as date) as VoteDate, 
     SUM(CASE WHEN Vote = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total
FROM      Votes
WHERE VoteDate between dateadd(day, -7, GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
GROUP BY  cast(VoteDate as date)
```

Your `VoteDate` column is a `datetime`, but you just want the `date` part of it. The easiest way to do that is to cast it as a `date` type. You can read more about SQL Server date types [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx).

And if your `Vote` column is either 1 or 0, you can just do `sum(vote) as Total` instead of doing the `case` statement.

Comment: To add to Eric's answer, you also might want to add a WHERE clause to first retrieve data for only last 7 (or N) days. Otherwise, you would perform the GROUPing operation on the full set (which could be very large) and then getting only the last 7 (or N) days worth of aggregated data.

Comment: Also, you can suggest to OP that changes `CASE WHEN Vote = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`by `Vote` or by `coalesce( vote, 0)`

Comment: @danihp - `Vote` does not appear to be null, so I don't know why'd I'd suggest `coalesce`. But, for T-SQL, I'd probably use `isnull` first, but you can find more here: http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/coalesce-vs-isnull-sql.html

Comment: @eric, oh, sorry, just by `vote` like I say on my comment ( or by isnull(...) if vote can contain null values ). You understand why OP needs a `case` ?

Comment: @Eric how  can display values where `count(*)` giving me 0? i was looking for solution of my problem, somehow i got here. Can you have a look at my problem http://bit.ly/Vx4Jni

Comment: Sorry I know this is old, but I found that the values in the WHERE clause need to be converted to DATEs as well, otherwise they're datetimes (which is what GETDATE somewhat counter-intuitively returns).  This means you're count for the farthest back day may be off. (eg if you run this at 5pm, something that happened at 4pm 7 days ago wouldnt get counted).  I used SQL like in the comment below to fix.

Comment: WHERE CAST (VOTEDATE as date) between CAST(dateadd(day, -7, GETDATE()) as DATE) and CAST( GETDATE() as DATE)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUM(Vote) As Total, YEAR(VoteDate),Month(VoteDate),Day(VoteDate)
FROM Votes
Group By YEAR(VoteDate),Month(VoteDate),Day(VoteDate)
```

[Some SQL Server functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) that may be of interest

[Some MySQL functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) that may be of interest