# T-SQL Calculate Total over X Period grouping by Date and Object

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, aggregate-functions

I have a large data set which for each day in the data set I need to calculate the aggregate activity for the previous 5, 7, and 10 days for every single row, and not just against the current date and this is not a straight running total overall time.. but for a specific period.

I have the daily aggregates built for the activity but having trouble aggregating date and object and then calculating the past X intervals for each individual row.

I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

So for example using -1 day (yesterday), -2 days, -3 days

- Day -1 (Previous Day/Yesterday)

  - Object A  2
  - Object B  231
  - Object C  232
- Day -2

  - Object A  5
  - Object B  117
  - Object C  127
- Day -3

  - Object A  9
  - Object B  200
  - Object C  175

My expected result would be running on current day (but NOT current date)

- Date, _TID  ,  1D,  2D, 3D (Columns)
- Date, Object A,   2,   7, 16
- Date, Object B, 231, 579, 779
- Date, Object C, 232, 359, 534

I looked at [How to Query Totals for Last 7 Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795874/how-to-query-to-get-totals-for-last-seven-days) and the better [SQL SUM of Last X Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067105/sql-sum-of-last-x-sum-of-records) but that is a sum total of all activity over the last X period and across all records and returned it for all rows,  where as I need the query to aggregate for the period specific to the object.

```html
;WITH [stSUM] AS
(
SELECT 
   TX._TID
   ,CAST(TX.DT_Req AS DATE) as AgrGrp
      ,TX.DayofYr
   ,TX.MofY
   ,TX.DayofM
   ,TX.DayofW
   ,TX.TrdPayDay
   ,TX.Hdy_Govt
   ,TX.Hdy_Novel
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN TX.TX_BG = 'Evt' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as EvtCnt
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN TX.TX_Yes=1 THEN TX.Rqt_Amt ELSE 0 END) as Amt
FROM CRS1.dbo.JustData
  Group By 
    CAST(TX.DT_Req AS DATE)
   ,TX._TID
      ,TX.DayofYr
   ,TX.MofY
      ,TX.DayofM
   ,TX.DayofW
   ,TX.TrdPayDay
   ,TX.Hdy_Govt
   ,TX.Hdy_Novel
) 
SELECT  AgrGrp, _TID,
  (select sum(Amt) from (select top 7 * from stSUM bd2 where bd2.AgrGrp <= AgrGrp order by AgrGrp desc) t1 )
        as Measured7,
      (select sum(Amt) from (select top 5 * from stSUM bd2 where bd2.AgrGrp <= AgrGrp order by AgrGrp desc) t2 )
        as Measured5
FROM [stSUM] 
GROUP BY AgrGrp, _TID
ORDER BY AgrGrp
```

But it produces output like this which is incorrect as each row should have a different value only reflecting the content of that _TID for the previous days. 
That is Measured7 is back to 2014-12-01 and Measured5 is back to 2014-12-03.

```html
AgrGrp     _TID Measured7 Measured5
2014-12-08 0101  14400     8620
2014-12-08 0558  14400     8620
2014-12-08 0537  14400     8620
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach was to summarize the day ranges I want in sub queries using a BETWEEN dates.

```
;with DayInfo as
(
select cast(runtime as date) [Date], 
targetType,
round(sum(duration),0) as duration
from Logs
group by cast(runtime as date), 
targetType)


select di.Date,
di.targetType,
di.duration,
d2.d2DurationSum,
d7.d7DurationSum
from DayInfo di
join (select d2.Date,
      d2.targetType,
      sum(dd2.duration) d2DurationSum
      from DayInfo d2
      join DayInfo dd2
      on dd2.Date between dateadd(day, -1, d2.Date) and d2.Date
      and d2.targetType = dd2.targetType
      group by d2.Date,
      d2.targetType) as d2
on di.Date = d2.Date
and di.targetType = d2.targetType
join (select d7.Date,
      d7.targetType,
      sum(dd7.duration) d7DurationSum
      from DayInfo d7
      join DayInfo dd7
      on dd7.Date between dateadd(day, -6, d7.Date) and d7.Date
      and d7.targetType = dd7.targetType
      group by d7.Date,
      d7.targetType) as d7
on di.Date = d7.Date
and di.targetType = d7.targetType
order by 1, 2
```

This gives the output like you described.

[image]